# Linkedin Company page updates

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I created a linkedIn application to get company page updates and post them on a webpage.

Every time I visit the page I have to log in to linkedIn (Oauth2) to get the feed.

Is it possible to remove the log in part so that when anyone visits the page they will see the update feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the LinkedIn access token lasts 60 days so you could store the oauth 2 access token e.g. database and just use that so you don't need to login every time.